# CodeIgniter Drivers : __call() method

Tags: php, codeigniter, libraries, drivers, magic-methods

I searched a lot and for a while for an answer to my question on **Stackoverflow** but I did not find an answer, not here neither elsewhere.

Anyways, I tried many times to use CodeIgniter's drivers but I often quit because of the **__call** method. Let me explain in an example.

Let's say I have a driver called **App** (that extends CI_Driver_Library of course)

```
class App extends CI_Driver_Library
{
    public $CI;
    public $valid_drivers;

    public function __constructor()
    {
        $this->CI &= get_instance();
        $this->valid_drivers = ['users']; // An example.
    }
}
```

Now I have the **users** driver like so.

```
class App_users extends CI_Driver 
{
    private $CI;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
        $this->CI->load->model('users_model');
    }

    public function __call($method, $params = [])
    {
        if (method_exists($this, $method)
        {
            return call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), $params);
        }
        elseif (method_exists($this->CI->users_model, $method))
        {
            return call_user_func_array(array($this->CI->users_model, $method), $params);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new BadMethodCallException("No such method: {$method}");
        }
    }
}
```

I want to load **Users_model** in this **App_users** __constructor (possible but **parent::$CI** is not accessible but I managed).

The problem I am facing is when using **__call** method to call whether this driver's method **OR** the model's method. Unfortunately, that magic method did not and never did work for me. How can I do it guys if possible? If not, is there any work-around?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us your implementation of `__call`.

Comment: @DFriend I edited the code and I added my implementation (please don't mind typos)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should know that the first if condition

```
if (method_exists($this, $method)...
```

is pointless because condition will never be satisfied. `__call` is magically triggered when a class method cannot be found. It has already been determined that `method_exists($this, $method)` is not TRUE. If it were TRUE then `__call()` would not have been triggered.

Removing the first `if` block results in this.

```
public function __call($method, $params = [])
{
    if (method_exists($this->CI->users_model, $method))
    {
        return call_user_func_array(array($this->CI->users_model, $method), $params);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new BadMethodCallException("No such method: {$method}");
    }
}
```

This should work.

If it does not I have to ask, what is the code that you would expect should trigger `__call`?

**Edit in reply to the comment:**

> tell me please.. Is there a way a child can access to its sibling's methods?

My first reaction is to say that if you have that need then "drivers" may not be the pattern to use. As implemented in CI, drivers are a special type of library that has a parent class and any number of potential child classes. Child classes have access to the parent class, but not their siblings.

This arrangement is on purpose because typically each driver is designed handle a singular type of device or particular software service. For instance, in the context of databases, each driver handles a particular type of database server (i.e. MySQL, SQLite) and/or extension to a server type  (i.e. mysql, mysqli).

The CI library `CI_Cache` has drivers for several different dynamic caching systems. These systems tend to be mutually exclusive. I suspect that trying to run `memcached` and `redis` at the same time would make for severe headaches.

These examples are why I wonder if you have not chosen the wrong software pattern. At the very least, the need for the siblings to communicate tends to point to wrong thinking when it comes to [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

All that said, I think the solution is to put a method in the parent that handles the chore. This method would be called from one sibling to the parent which would call the appropriate method in the other sibling. Note: I have not tested this idea. `__call` might be able to handle this but it seems to me that explicit calls is a cleaner solution.

In case you haven't found them already here are a couple of CI Drivers tutorials that you might find helpful. [Kevin Phillips](http://www.kevinphillips.co.nz/news/codeigniter-drivers-tutorial/) and [codebyjeff](http://codebyjeff.com/blog/2012/01/forms-with-less-pain-using-ci-drivers)

Comment: :'( .. For every project I did, I gave up using CodeIgniter Drivers because of this and you came and made my life happier :) ... This is what I was looking for for more than two (2) years! Solved in one day thanks to you and Stackoverflow <3

Comment: tell me please @DFriend .. Is there a way a child can access to its sibling's methods?

Comment: I added some to my answer to address the above comment.